# Using OpenCV to process live video from Phantom 4

Tags: ios, opencv, dji-sdk

I would like to process frames live in OpenCV from the video feed on a DJI Phantom 4. I've been able to set up OpenCV for iOS in xCode but I need help finding a tutorial/instructions on how to send the frames over from the DJI Camera into OpenCV in the correct format on the fly. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You should get the frames from dji SDK, then convert it to opencv Mat. Read the documentation for getting frames from dji sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there Ilia Labkovsky,

I think am in the same boat, I have got a P3 and would like to process the images via OpenCV. I am intending to use my laptop PC as an image processor, sending the images directly via TCP/IP and doing my own image processing off-board. I am yet to establish this though, I may come across some problems.

Is there a way I can privately message you on Stack Overflow?

Best of luck with the programming :)

Comment: email me: labkovsk@usc.edu

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for Android on the DJI sample apps on how to parse and obtain the yuv frames. From there you can use openCv to process the frames: https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample

Comment: Thanks, but looking for iOS info